# Error while deploying Apache Storm to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-storm

Trying to deploy a Storm topology on AWS. Tried running the (old) standard [storm-deploy](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-deploy) project on my Mac OS X machine. Getting following error while deploying the storm cluster

```
DEBUG execute - out
=> "/Users/himanshuyadav/.ssh/id_rsa\n"
DEBUG jclouds - Found jclouds sshj driver
DEBUG jclouds - extensions (:log4j :slf4j :sshj)
DEBUG jclouds - options [:jclouds.regions "us-east-1" :blobstore-provider "aws-s3"]
ERROR logging - Exception in thread "main"
ERROR logging - com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) org.jclouds.rest.RestContext<org.jclouds.aws.ec2.AWSEC2Client, A> cannot be used as a key; It is not fully specified.

1 error (form-init1868462685526062633.clj:1)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5440)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
ERROR logging - at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
```

From my side I have tried to upgrade JDK 1.7.0_65 to 1.8.0_31 but no luck so far.
Other than that tried to replace ssh key location with AWS's `.pem` keys but did not work as well.

I understand that storm-deploy is an old project which worked with previous version. Is there any new version/other way of deploying storm-topology on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the same issue. Try with the "install-0.9.1" branch and JDK 1.7. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-development/XuTjxKY7qrI) **downgrading JRE specifically to version 1.7.0_45 did the trick for me**.

Thread suggests anything above JRE version 1.7.0_51 wont work! Follow [these steps to downgrade to an older version of JRE](https://askubuntu.com/a/549919/386697)